# Input box type month required to have pointer on icon when hover

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I have a pointer cursor on the input box except for the icon

```
<input class="form-control"  type="month" [value]="currentDate" 
          id="bdaymonth" name="bdaymonth" 
         (change)="monthYearDisplay($event)" >
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: change is the function? It'll be much better if you can be descriptive instead of scheming the guideline of posting a question.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? And what preprocessor?